# Sequences and pseudocharacter in compact spaces

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is there a consistent example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$ on which the following holds?

i) there is a $Y \in {[X]}^{\aleph_1}$ such that $\psi (Y) = \aleph_1$; and

ii) there is no non-trivial converging sequence of type $\omega_1$ in $X$.

Note that the negation of (ii) implies (i) (assuming ZFC of course).

I know only one example of a compact Hausdorff space $X$, with $\psi (X) \geq \aleph_1$, satisfying (ii). It is the one-point compactification $X$ of the (very complex) locally compact space $Y$ constructed in

> I. Juhász, P. Koszmider and L. Soukup,
>   *A first countable, initially $\omega_{1}$-compact but non-compact space*,
>   Topology and its Applications **156** (2009), 1863-1879.
>   doi:[10.1016/j.topol.2009.04.004](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.topol.2009.04.004)

In this case, I don't know if $X$ satisfies (i).

Comment: By "a converging sequence of type $\omega_1$", do you mean a copy of $\omega_1$ with the order topology, converging to some $x$ in the sense that any neighborhood of $x$ contains a terminal part ?

Comment: Essentially, yes. But not necessarily with the order topology in the whole sequence. The important thing to me here is: "any neighborhood of $x$ contains a terminal part".

Comment: Let me fix the following definition: a non-trivial converging sequence of type $\omega_1$ in $X$ to $x \in X$, is a injective $f: \omega_1 \rightarrow X$ such that $| f [\omega_1] \setminus O| \leq \aleph_0$ for every open neighborhood $O$ of $x$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Unfortunately I don't have any example at hand.

Comment: What is $\psi$?

Comment: $\psi$ is the cardinal function pseudo-character: $\psi (X)$ is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that each point of $X$ is the intersection of a family of cardinality $\leq \kappa$ of sets which are open in $X$.

Comment: What is ${[X]}^{\aleph_1}$? A family of closed subspaces of density $\aleph_1$?

Comment: No, it is the family of all subspaces of $X$ of cardinality $\aleph_1$.